# Only show table data on todays date

Tags: javascript, html, tablesorter

Ok so I have a table with information. Inside of this table are the columns namer and date (DD-MM-YYYY).

I need to restrict the table to only showing rows in my table that have a date that is equal to the current date. So if there are 10 rows and only 5 of them have today's date in the date column, only those 5 should show.

So I wondered if anyone knew of any code that would show only the rows on todays date, and change date automatically everyday.

Current HTML

```
<table class="tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Release Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter Parker</td>
        <td>11/07/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John Hood</td>
        <td>12/07/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Clark Kent</td>
        <td>12/07/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bruce Almighty</td>
        <td>13/07/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bruce Evans</td>
        <td>14/07/2015</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Current Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("table").tablesorter({
    headers: {
        0: {
            sorter: false
        },
        1: {
            sorter: false
        },
        2: {
            sorter: false
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: You have to make query to your database with **where** condition in date, example : select * from mytable where date=[today].

Comment: how to you bring the data from the database....and what is the table structure?

Comment: how does this table get populated ? If data is sucked down from a database, it is much better to apply the restriction on the server side, if you are allowed to do so. Rule of thumb is not to trust the client side. If you pass data to the client and try to hide some part of it, a smart client **can still see** these data. So if you want to restrict your client from accessing some data, do not give the data in her hands at the first place.

Comment: I currently dont use a database, I input the table data straight into the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing this before they appear in the HTML, but here is how to do it with jQuery.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    var t = new Date();
    $("tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().match(/(\d+)/g);
        var d = new Date(text[2], text[1] - 1, text[0]);
        if (d.toDateString() == t.toDateString()) {
            var d = new Date(text[2], text[1] - 1, text[0]);
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('hidden');
        };
    });
});
```

Today's dat eis defined. The function will cycle through the second `TD` in each `TR`, define a date from the text inside (using regex-match to separate the date components), compare that to today's date, and if they are the same it will add the `hidden` class to the whole row.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc4jfn5g/)

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Forgive me, I didn't read the question properly! It seems you want to hide those that don't have today's date. In that case change the `==` in the if block to `!=`. This will do the opposite. [JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc4jfn5g/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but this only highlights the row data, I need to hide the data completely and only show data with todays date.

Comment: I did that so you could choose how to hide the data. Just add `visibility: hidden` to the .hidden style...

Comment: Ahhh sorry. Perfect. Will this automatically then change date everyday?

Comment: No problem. Yes, it will.